# Is it ok nowadays to say numbers instead of digits, while expressing a sum?

Tags: british-english, numbers

( example: 2345 - these four numbers make the sum..) or must I say digits?

Comment: Nowadays or any day, numbers are numbers, digits are digits. One **can not** substitute one word for the other. However, note that the definition of *number* includes "digit" as a synonym.

Comment: The words have, and have had for a long time, different meanings. Thus 2 + 3 = 5 uses three numbers and three digits (as each number is single-digit) whereas 7 + 5 = 12 contains three numbers but four digits.

Comment: This is not to say that there is not a confusion over usages. Statements like '... will also explain to the students that when 6-digit figure is written in words how they will write it in numbers' [DA MODEL HIGH SCHOOL PHASE IV.docx] are better avoided.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Look up "write in numbers" idiomatic expression.

Comment: Thank you for the kind and prompt replies. In particular reference to Kris's comment, I just want to say that I don't nor didn't mean to underestimate or substitute words, but: at the moment I am preparing a small commercial text ( to go along a popular shoe label that will be sold in India, Africa, Europe, the Americas, ext), so I was thinking that  for such an international market the word 'number' may sound a little easier to read ( grasp)  than the word digit… Thank you all :)

Comment: As @Kris rightly said, numbers are numbers and digits are digits, be it in the *age of roman empire* or the *age of computers*. It is like saying: should I speak out an entire word or the individual characters in it? They are both related concepts but entirely different in essence!

Comment: A slightly pointy-headed answer is that the distinction should be between digits and **numerals**. *Number* is abstract; *numeral* is the concrete expression of a number and is composed of digits.

Comment: It's more important now than it ever has been to be precise with numeric terminology.

Comment: @Kris I have done as you have ordered, but don't see anything relevant in the first 10 of millions of claimed results. Have you a point?

Comment: @Kris Would you mind explaining how 'One can not substitute one word for the other. However, note that the definition of _number_ includes "digit" as a synonym.' can possibly make sense?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Synonym is not the same as meaning. Synonyms are not always interchangeable. Please see also: [ell.se].

Comment: @Kris Synonyms are always interchangeable in at least some contexts. Otherwise they're not synonyms. This has been covered on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *always* is not the same as "in at least some contexts" :)

Comment: @Kris But 'Nowadays or any day, numbers are numbers, digits are digits. One can not substitute one word for the other.' generalises wrongly.

Answer (score 4):

No you can't. Take for example this set of numbers: {1, 545, 42, 2640}

In that set there are **ten digits**, but only **four numbers**.

545 is a number with three digits. However, if the digits were separated, i.e. 5, 4, 5, then you will have three digits and three numbers.

Answer (score 1):

[Digit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/digit):

> - One of the ten Arabic number symbols, 0 through 9.

[Number](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/number):

> - A member of any of the following sets of mathematical objects: integers, rational numbers, real numbers, and complex numbers. These sets can be derived from the positive integers through various algebraic and analytic constructions.

**1**:  is both  a digit and a number (a single digit number).

**326**:  is a number made up of three digits, a three-digit number.

As for you example  *2, 3, 4 and 5*  are four numbers (single digit numbers). To sum them up I'd refer to them as numbers rather than digits.

Comment: @terdon - I fixed it!!

Answer (score 1):

No, we cannot substitute digit with number.

The difference between a digit and a number is similar to the difference between an alphabet and a word which will always remain the way it has been.

Just like alphabetics make words, digits make numbers.

Comment: Why do people say 'Write two hundred and fifty in numbers' then?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth dunno, but that equals 200.50 (and it should be *numerically*).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : Normally people could say it but I am sure that is not mathematically correct. This would otherwise resolve the very use of digits. We always say the digit at nth place but never number at nth place. Just doesn't sound right to the ears.

Comment: English usage isn't as well-defined as maths usage (and there are even disputes over terminology amongst mathematicians, and certainly amongst maths teachers). "[We] cannot substitute 'digit' with 'number' " is not quite the whole story, but the two terms overlap in usage only to a small degree.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : yes, you are right and you definitely know better.. but Silvia wants to know if it is appropriate to use. I would like to advise that it's better to keep them separate.

Comment: 'No, we cannot substitute digit with number' =/= 'I would like to advise that it's better to keep them separate'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : I am still sticking to my first statement and that's what is correct : 'No, we cannot substitute digit with number' !